# How to read the contents of files of a folder dragged and dropped in html5

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, electron

There are many questions in stack overflow and the internet in general regarding this error, however, the context in which most of them are asked and answered does not match mine. I am making a gallery app with electron. The idea is for someone to drag a folder into a dropzone in the app, and the app opens the folder, iterates through each item in the folder, if it finds a folder, it just displays the name of the folder, if its an image, read the image and display it to the user. (Note, I have not explicitly checked the file type to be image. I am dragging a folder whose contents I am certain are either an image or a folder...I will add type checking later). Here is my code.

```
"use strict"
const filedrop = document.getElementById('drop-zone')
const importMyDrop = function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault()
  const files = e.dataTransfer.items
  if (files.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          let entry = e.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry()
          if (entry.isFile) {
              console.log("file")
          } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
              onInitFs(entry)
          }
      }

    }
  }
 const importDragOver = function (e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy'
   e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
   return false
  }

  function toArray(list) {
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0)
}

  function listResults(entries) {
    let list = document.getElementById('list')

    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
       if (entry.isDirectory) {
         list.innerHTML += `<li>${entry.name}</li>`
       }
       else if (entry.isFile) {
           let reader = new FileReader()
           reader.onloadend = function (e) {
              list.innerHTML += "<p><strong>" + entry.name + ":</strong><br />" +
                '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" /></p>'
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(entry)//Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
    }
})
 }
  function onInitFs(fs) {
    let dirReader = fs.createReader()
    let entries = []

   // Call the reader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.
    let readEntries = function () {
    dirReader.readEntries(function (results) {
        if (!results.length) {
            listResults(entries.sort())
        } else {
            entries = entries.concat(toArray(results))
            readEntries()
        }
    })
}

readEntries() // Start reading dirs.

}

 filedrop.addEventListener('drop', importMyDrop)
 filedrop.addEventListener('dragover', importDragOver)
```

The error is shown in the comment of the following line

```
reader.readAsDataURL(entry)//Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

I am following [this post](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), and an example by [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-open-dropped-files/). Instructions in the first link go as far as iterating through each content of the folder, which I have successfully done. The second link shows how to display the image when it is drag and dropped. The only issue is that in my app, instead of dropping an image, the user will drop a folder and iterate through its contents.
How do I solve this error?

Comment: you should change your logic, dont use ```readAsDataURL``` if it is a directory, currently you call that function regardless if its a dir or file

Comment: I only use `readDataURL` when its a file. Look at function `listResults(entries)`. I have also tried dropping a folder which contains one image file only and it displays the same error